# Emitting warnings on GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a way that I could pass a string message as a warnign in GCC (but not as an ordinary message)?

Comment: Do you want to insert your own warning in GCC or what?

Comment: Like?.. for what kind of warning?

Comment: I assume a warning should be emitted depending on some preprocessor conditions (i.e. the warning message would be wrapped in `#if` or `#ifdef`).

Comment: @suddnely_me I want to insert my own warning into my code (while metaprogramming this feature is sometimes useful).

Answer (score 6):

(googled:)

`#error` works and needs to, because the standard mandates it. gcc also has `#warning`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use warning about usunused variable for this - http://www.ideone.com/GyAMq

```
if(1 < 0) {
            char warning__1_Should_not_be_less_than_0;
    }
```